# Removing documents from a site that are not linked

Tags: list, pdf, web-crawler, document, intranet

I took over an Intranet site that has ~20K documents that have been linked at one time or another over 7 years.  Roughly, 2.8K of the documents are linked.  Is there a way or tool to create a list of documents within a series of folders that are NOT linked so I can delete?

I know this isn't a "programming" question directly but I'm betting I'm not the only web programmer that faces this dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might get what you want using following steps:

1. Create list of your files on disk using OS commands like [dir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2376808/249690) or [ls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1767559/249690)
2. Build list of linked documents using [Xenu Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) or a similar tool.
3. Find all entries in the first list that are not present in the second list.
4. Remove files that correspond to entries found on step 3
5. Run Xenu Link Sleuth again to make sure you didn't remove anything useful.