# How to get the full file names from multiple folders through command line into a csv

Tags: powershell, command-line, command-prompt

Thanks to a couple people here I am able to connect to my WD NAS through command line.

Now I want to get the titles of the the movies I have stored there. I know about the `dir /b > file.csv` command, but this doesn't seem to work for my structure. I have a folder named Data (which I have X: mapped to this spot "\MYNAS\Data") and within the Data folder I have other folders such as Action, Drama, Documentary etc. So when I use the `dir /b > file.csv` command, it gives me the folder names inside Data and not the movies inside the folders.

Is there an easy way to pull the files from within each folder and make them all output to one CSV instead of going through and making a sperate csv for each folder?

I would prefer to solve this with command prompt because I am the most familiar with it, but I am open to using powershell as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursive directory listing in dos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376801/recursive-directory-listing-in-dos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the `dir` command in `cmd.exe`, you'll need the `/S` switch to go through the folder recursively, and possibly `/A:-D` to exclude directories and junctions from the result:

```
dir X:\Data /A:-D /S /B > files.csv
```

You could also use PowerShell, the equivalent cmdlet would be [`Get-ChildItem`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx):

```
Get-ChildItem X:\Data -File -Recurse | select FullName | Out-File "files.csv"
```

As @Matt notes, this statement only works in PowerShell Version 3.0 or above. In earlier versions, the `-File` parameter doesn't work, so you'll have to filter directories out manually:

```
Get-ChildItem X:\Data -Recurse | Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer} | Select FullName | Out-File "files.csv"
```

You can expand the `Where-Object` filter to exclude files with certain extensions with the `Extension` property:

```
$ExcludeExtensions = ".exe",".pdf"
Get-ChildItem X:\Data -Recurse | Where-Object {(-not $_.PSIsContainer) -and ($ExcludeExtensions -notcontains $_.Extension)} | Select FullName | Out-File "files.csv"
```

Comment: Note that you would need PowerShell 3.0 for that to work.

Comment: I tried the first suggestion you gave me and once I omitted the \Data part it worked, except it is now giving me the full path of each file. So for example, instead of it just saying 'District 9', it is showing it as 'X:/Data/Distrcit9'. Any ideas for just getting the name and not the full location?

Comment: @MasonEvans Sorry, but I think the full path output when using `/s` is by design. With PowerShell you can `Select Name` instead of `Select FullName` to just get the file name

Comment: Okay thanks, and one last thing, what is the 'A:' for in that first example?

Comment: `/A` is the `attribute` switch, see `dir /?` for more info

Comment: I marked this as solved; however I've changed my mind and want to filter out the directories with powershell. I am getting this error when I use your second powershell suggestion (using powershell < 3.0) http://i.imgur.com/OL9SCUc.png; however this next picture proves I do have it mounted as X: http://i.imgur.com/tzLBwDq.png Anything I'm missing? I've also changed the script to say just X: instead of X:\Data since I think I have X: going straight into that Data folder already, but with or without the \Data it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @MasonEvans if you're running PowerShell as administrator, you also need to map the drive "as administrator". Please see: http://serverfault.com/questions/673349/access-already-mapped-network-drive-in-powershell

Comment: Awesome, now to filter out certain file types (.exe) I added the follwing: ? { $_.Name -notlike "*.exe" } however it is now showing the info inside the powershell console and not outputting the info into a csv. Here is what the code fully looks like: http://i.imgur.com/VUqmpXN.png Did I place it in the correct spot? EDIT: Nevermind, I got it. I forgot to add the pipe after the -notlike section. Thanks for your help Mathias.

Comment: @MasonEvans Yeah, you need a pipe between the second `?` statement and `Select`. I've updated the answer with another example showing how to exclude multiple extensions