# Command for listing all folders in the system

Tags: windows

I tried searching for a command that could list all the file in a directory as well as subfolders using a command prompt command.

I have read the help for "dir" command but coudn't find what I was looking for.

Please help me what command could get this.

Comment: Why won't `dir /s /b` suffice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive directory listing in dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376801/recursive-directory-listing-in-dos)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/344155/how-do-i-recursively-list-filenames-only-in-dos-windows

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are looking for `tree /F`

Check out it here: https://www.computerhope.com/treehlp.htm